# How can I use marks to jump to locations in files I have recently opened, but not changed?

Tags: cursor-motions

Often times I edit a file - think my work is done - then close the file and move on to the next thing. But then I realise I need to go back to that code and tweak it a bit more.
If I open the file again, I can  use the `.` mark and jump to the position of the last edit with `'.`.
Now I'm trying to find a way to use vim's marks to jump to locations in files I have recently visited, but not changed.
I know I can set a mark manually, but most of the time, I don't expect to come back and so I don't set a mark and need to use a mark that vim generates automatically.
The `"` mark seems like this could be a way to achieve this, from `:h motion`.

> `"`           To the cursor position when last exiting the current
>               buffer.  Defaults to the first character of the first
>               line.  See |last-position-jump| for how to use this
>               for each opened file.
>               Only one position is remembered per buffer, not one
>               for each window.  As long as the buffer is visible in
>               a window the position won't be changed.
>               {not in Vi}.

However  if I

- close all windows showing a buffer (but the buffer is still present in the buffer list). or:
- kill all instances of the buffer

the mark doesn't seem to update, how can I use a mark to jump to a location of the last cursor position in the buffer/file?

Comment: I think you are looking for `Ctrl+o` and `Ctrl+i` ... `:h jump-motions` for more info

Comment: @spasic thats not a bad suggestion, but once you make a  few dozen jumps, the position would be lost in a massive jump list. By scoping the marks to the buffer you  have a smaller list of marks/locations to manage

Comment: If you didn't read it already, I think [this tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_cursor_to_file_position_in_previous_editing_session) would be interesting. Maybe you'll have to tweak your `viminfo`

Comment: @statox  thanks. I saw that and the tip in the vim help. I think those solutions cause automatic jumping to the `"` mark when you open a file. I really wanted to only jump to the last cursor position manually. Also, I just couldn't make sense of when the `"` mark gets set and updated so to me the `"` mark is unusable.

Comment: Quite frankly, I find this question confusing, but I'd like to help.  Thus, if @the_velour_fog is still around, it would be great to hear some additional explanations and see what can be done to achieve the desired `vim` behavior.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a classic solution: use

```
`H
```

to jump to the last HTML file and so on…

```
augroup VIMRC
  autocmd!

  autocmd BufLeave *.css  normal! mC
  autocmd BufLeave *.html normal! mH
  autocmd BufLeave *.js   normal! mJ
  autocmd BufLeave *.php  normal! mP
augroup END
```

Comment: thanks, this seems like it could really be useful. I've loaded it into my vimrc to try it out. I've changed to autocmd to `WinLeave` as I've noticed `BufLeave` doesn't seem to fire when you close a split and the buffer is still open somewhere else. I know its a bit of an edge case, but `WinLeave` seems to work over a wider range of "file closing" type situations, but I'm still just testing...

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this vimscript statement which seems to work

```
autocmd BufLeave * :normal ml
```

#### Explanation

- `BufLeave` auto command: this seems to trigger when you

  - move to another window
  - when you close the **last** window displaying the buffer
  - when you close the buffer itself with `bd`
- `:normal` - it seems by default, the `command` part of autocmd is an ex command. So to tell vim  to run  a normal mode command , you need to add `:normal`
- `ml` - set a mark `l` (mnemonic: *last*)

#### Usage

to recall the cursor position from the last time you were in the buffer simply hit

```
'l
```

or

```
`l
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like your cursor to restore the last position known to *viminfo*, you can use

```
autocmd BufReadPost * call setpos(".", getpos("'\""))
```

---

romainl's answer has been particularly useful to me, and I have been using this a lot (since I am a web dev):

```
augroup VIMRC
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufLeave,WinLeave *.html normal! mH
    autocmd BufLeave,WinLeave *.css normal! mC
    autocmd BufLeave,WinLeave *.js normal! mJ
augroup end

nnoremap <space>h `Hzz
nnoremap <space>c `Czz
nnoremap <space>j `Jzz
```

---

The final potentially useful thing is the option, `:help 'nostartofline`:

```
               *'startofline'* *'sol'* *'nostartofline'* *'nosol'*
'startofline' 'sol' boolean (default on)
            global
            {not in Vi}
    When "on" the commands listed below move the cursor to the first
    non-blank of the line.  When off the cursor is kept in the same column
    (if possible).  This applies to the commands: CTRL-D, CTRL-U, CTRL-B,
    CTRL-F, "G", "H", "M", "L", gg, and to the commands "d", "<<" and ">>"
    with a linewise operator, with "%" with a count and to buffer changing
    commands (CTRL-^, :bnext, :bNext, etc.).  Also for an Ex command that
    only has a line number, e.g., ":25" or ":+".
    In case of buffer changing commands the cursor is placed at the column
    where it was the last time the buffer was edited.
    NOTE: This option is set when 'compatible' is set.
```