# autocmd mark statements causing problems with nerd tree and netrw?

Tags: netrw, plugin-nerdtree

In order to automatically trigger a mark holding the last cursor position when I left a buffer or window, I added these statements to my `~/.vimrc`:
<sub>for more background on why I wanted to add these commands please refer to [this vi.stackexchange question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8169/how-can-i-use-marks-to-jump-to-locations-in-files-i-have-recently-opened-but-no)</sub>.

```
autocmd BufLeave * :normal mB
autocmd WinLeave * :normal mW
```

The statements are causing errors when moving out of, or closing buffers created by `NERDTree` or `netrw`. e.g. when closing a `netrw` buffer.

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>85_NetrwBookHistHandler:
line  154:
E121: Undefined variable: g:netrw_bookmarklist
E15: Invalid expression: g:netrw_bookmarklist[iremove - 1]
line  158:
E121: Undefined variable: g:netrw_bookmarklist
E116: Invalid arguments for function remove
line  159:
E121: Undefined variable: dremove
```

Also NERDTree is sometimes making addiditonal copies of directories, so when I run `git status`, git is showing new  directories.
I suspect the cause of the error is the fact that NERDTree and netrw are creating new mappings, so that the command `:normal mB` when executed in a  NERDTree buffer is triggering something like `m`,`l` -which in NERDTree mappings means "modify" and "list" rather than set a new mark.
Does this reasoning sound right?
If so how could I detect when focus is in a NERDTree or netrw buffer, so the mappings can be turned off. Otherwise what could the cause to this problem?

Comment: If you add a bang after `:normal`, does it change anything? A bang just after `:normal` means that the keys you give as an argument won't be remapped. If the keys are not remapped, maybe your autocmd will simply set marks and not call `netrw` or `NERDTree`'s functions.

Comment: @user9433424 thanks alot! I've added the `!` and so far its working nicely. I knew the `!` after a function name would allow you to redefine the function. But I didn't know about the `!`  in autocmd / `normal` statements. so it basically locks the command in, so that it can't be remapped? . Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Yes, I think what you said is right, it basically locks the command in. They talk about this in `:help :normal`. Also in the 15th and 16th chapter of Learn Vimscript the Hard Way. There are various Ex commands whose behavior is changed when you append a bang to them (like `:retab` or `:join`). When you think your problem is solved, you could post your solution as an answer.

Comment: @user9433424 yes, I looked at the answer romainl gave on my previous question, and he used `:normal!` form too. So based on my testing and the assumption romainl has likely used the command without issues I guess its a workable answer that might help others.

Answer (score 1):

per user9433424 comments this is working so far without issues.

```
autocmd BufLeave * :normal! mb 
autocmd WinLeave * :normal! mw
```

I'm guessing using this command may mean the original functions netrw and NERDTree assigned to the `mb` and `mw` maps may be lost, but for me, I wasn't using them anyway.